# Luaotfload complains: "cache : Could not write lookup cache"

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, luaotfload

I am in quite the pickle about my document I would like to compile with LuaLaTeX.

This is the set-up I am using for the fonts and such:

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[rm]{titlesec}
%\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[Numbers=Proportional]{Adobe Caslon Pro}
```

Until now this posed no problem and gave me no errors, but now it does.
`luaotfload` complains that it cannot write into the lookupcache or the cache.
I don't know what to do about this.

Seems solved...

Comment: Hello all, I have specified the name of the font explicitly and that seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: Interesting, I ran the code as you had it and it compiled just fine for me using TeXLive 2013. If you haven't upgraded you might consider doing that as well.

Comment: No, I am running TexLive 2013 too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run in a terminal

```
luaotfload-tool --update
```

and then try again. I have no problem with your example. I have the Caslon font in `~/.fonts/Caslon/`

Comment: I guess this would also help, but as I stated at the bottom, the font is not a problem anymore. Still, thank you for the answer.

Comment: I should have taken this advice more seriously! One needs to run the update via the tool or else you might not get errors by the compiler but it sure as heck will not compile the document. Thanks again for this very helpful advice.